# How can I customize some of the Explorer's background colours for the selected item in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, customization, background-color

I have simply question. How can i set background color for active file in unfocused sidebar in Visual Studio Code. In the picture, you can see it a little bit.

[image]

Also i'd like to ask you for another 2 things about customization.
How can i set border color on hover with transparent background.

[image]

How to set background color for active file in focused sidebar.

Comment: there are a limited number of theme colors to try, most of them are not relevant, try all the others

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, there are no dedicated settings for the explorer's listing colours. There are settings for list colours in general.

The settings you are looking for are:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#880000",
    "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#ff0000",
    "list.hoverBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```

If you have set `"explorer.autoReveal": false`, you may want to remove that or set that to `true`.